# Generalizations of the golden and silver ratios, and their significance

Tags: algebra-precalculus, irrational-numbers, golden-ratio

$\Phi$, or the *golden ratio*, is basically $\frac{a+b}{a}=\frac{a}{b}$. The *silver ratio* corresponds to a similar idea of: $\frac{2a+b}{a}=\frac{a}{b}$. I've read on Wikipedia that both of these ratios are well known and have some appearance in nature (not the mystical hogwash stuff). In addition, there is the relation of the *Fibonacci* and *Pell* Numbers respectively.

Funny enough, I stumbled on these ratios originally by myself just messing around with numbers. I also noticed that the silver ratio minus *1* approximates $\sqrt{2}$ (which is how I came to be fooling around with this).

However I don't seem to find anything about further manipulation of this ratio, such as: $\frac{3a+b}{a}=\frac{a}{b}$, $\frac{4a+b}{a}=\frac{a}{b}$ and so forth. Do these ratios have any special properties that are found in nature? Perhaps called the copper ratio or something?

Comment: The silver ratio doesn't 'approximate' $1+\sqrt{2}$; that's exactly what it is.  If you rewrite your ratios non-homogeneously using $x=\frac{a}{b}$, you get $x=2+\frac1x$; multiplying by $x$ turns this into the quadratic equation $x^2-2x-1=0$ with solution $1+\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: They have less and less importance as you increase in the height. If you look at the wikipedia page on the silver ratio (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silver_ratio) you can find section on "silver means" that generalizes it to "metallic means" and then specifically mentions the "bronze mean".

Comment: Ok, thanks. But this brings me to another ratio. What about (a+2b)/a=a/b? This comes out to (sqrt(3)+1)/2. Does this ratio ever appear in nature or have some use?

Answer (score 3):

Answer thanks to Foo Barrigno:

> They have less and less importance as you increase in the height. If you look at the wikipedia page on the silver ratio (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silver_ratio) you can find section on "silver means" that generalizes it to "metallic means" and then specifically mentions the "bronze mean".

Answer (score 3):

[This paper (The Generalizations of the Golden Ratio: Their Powers, Continued Fractions, and Convergents, pdf)](http://web.mit.edu/primes/materials/2011/Kalia-Generalizations.pdf) proposes alternative way of defining silver means and related numbers and sequences.

*Golden ratio* can be defined as a continued fraction as follows:

$$1+\cfrac1{1 + \cfrac1{1 + \cfrac1{\cdots}}}=\cfrac{1+\sqrt5}{2}=\phi$$

*Silver ratio* is then:

$$2+\cfrac1{2 + \cfrac1{2 + \cfrac1{\cdots}}}={1+\sqrt2}=\delta_S$$

Now, there is a generalization of golden and silver ratio, called *Silver mean of order n* that is defined with following continued fraction:

$$N+\cfrac1{N + \cfrac1{N + \cfrac1{\cdots}}}=\cfrac{N+\sqrt{N^2+4}}{2}$$

Silver means are summarized in the following table:

[image]

Releted to this, the authors also define *silver Fibonacci sequences*:

*Fibonacci sequence* is defined with recurrence $F_{n+2}=F_{n+1}+F_{n}$ where $F_0=0$ and $F_1=1$.

Family of *silver Fibonacci sequences* is defined with recurrence $F_{m,n+2}=mF_{m,n+1}+F_{m,n}$ where $F_{m,0}=0$ and $F_{m,1}=1$.

Relationship between silver means and silver Fibonacci sequences (and many other related interesting things) are explored in the paper.